# grpc stream: Cannot check peer: missing selected ALPN property

Tags: ssl-certificate, grpc, http2, envoyproxy

I'm using c++ to develop a pair of grpc stream server and client without any certificate. It worked as expected.

Then I want to use Envoy as the gateway of the server. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
          secure            insecure
client ----------- Envoy -------------server
```

In other words, I want to create grpc connection with certificate between the client and the Envoy. But after deploying the Envoy and the server, I always get the error:

```
StreamData rpc failed: failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:172.16.0.3:1444: Cannot check peer: missing selected ALPN property.
```

My machines are CentOS 7 and the versions of `openssl` are `OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021`.

Here is my codes and my config of Envoy: https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/26172